# Symfony2: Unable to override standard error template?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to override the standard `error.html.twig` template provided by the Symfony2 Twig Bundle.

According to [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html), I just need to place a file `error.html.twig` in my `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` folder and Symfony should use it.

I *am* able to specify specific error templates, like `error404.html.twig`, and those are used. But I'm looking to create a catch all template as well.

Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: When you attempt to overwrite `error.html.twig`, what template does it actually use?

Comment: I did the same for my error page and it works. Try to physically remove cache in `app/cache` and run `app/console cache:clear` after that.

Comment: Hmm removing the whole cache seems to have helped. Thansk

Answer (score 0):

The answer here seems to be clearing your cache after adding or editing your template.

A simple `app/console cache:clear` should resolve your problems also manually removing the `app/cache` directory should accomplish the same thing.